# Is there a pin header with 3mm pitch similar to the 0.1" pitch headers?

Tags: connector, pins, prototyping, header

Is there a standard pin header with a 3mm pitch that is similar to the common 0.1" pitch pin headers (shown in photo below)? I'm not even sure what the correct name for these are. What is the best way to search for a part like this on Mouser or Digikey? My searches keep coming up with weird shrouded plastic housing things.
Thanks!

[image: 0.1" pitch pin header]

The part I was interested in connecting to is similar to this, with half-holes along the edges:

[image: 3mm pitch connection points]

Comment: I searched extensively for any sort of 3mm pitch pin header before posting. Could you share what you found?

Comment: Those pins are separable. So separate them and populate 3mm spaced holes on a PCB with them.

Comment: I find headers separated at single quantities to be weakened and easily slide out of their plastic.

Comment: Why exactly do you need 3mm pitch? Is there another connector you need to mate with? If so, what does the manufacturer recommend? In any case, shopping questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I am not looking for shopping recommendations, I am looking for information on what this type of connector is called and how to find it.

Comment: Dave, I updated the question with a photo of the mating part. The manufacturer recommends soldering the part to a custom made PCB. I was just wondering if there was a 3mm pitch system similar to the common 0.1" system.

Comment: The PCB probably solders right to another PCB, I don't think the holes were intended for pins. Check the landing pattern in the documentation you didn't provide

Comment: The half-holes around the edges are called [castellations](http://www.pcbfabrication.com/pcb-fabrication/Castellated_Hole_PCB.asp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google found many examples. For example: http://wppro.com/content/en/products/pin-headers/3mm-pitch/product/973.html

Comment: I guess this answers my question. It looks like there aren't any available from Mouser or Digikey or similiar though. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option for "odd" devices such as this is to design a simple dual-sided PCB with the 3mm castellation landing pads on top, and 0.1" header on bottom. Solder the device to the PCB, install the 0.1" header, and plug into your board. Of course this is solely to make the device modular; if you didn't need modularity, just solder the device directly.